# Disable did_you_mean gem from within a script

Tags: ruby

I read that you can disable the `did_you_mean` gem (which is enabled by default) via the Ruby command line like so:

```
ruby --disable-did_you_mean script.rb
```

Is there a way to the same from within `script.rb` instead of the command line parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure what use-case this might have...? Wouldn't handling exceptions within the script make better sense?

Comment: @Myst: While extending a rather big project (running in an embedded ruby interpreter), I am sometimes seeing when I misspell a name, the interpreter is busy and starts eating up all the machine's memory (which takes a while) before it fails and tells me the name doesn't exist. I am trying to test whether disabling `did_you_mean` has any effect on this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can undo the [module definition of `DidYouMean`](https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean/blob/master/lib/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb) by re-implementing in your `script.rb`, wherein you delegate the error handler to original Ruby implementation.

```
# Beginning of script.rb
module DidYouMean
  module Correctable
    prepend_features NameError
    def to_s
      super
    end
  end
end

ary = [1,2]
ary.att(0)

#=> undefined method `att' for [1, 2]:Array
#   (repl):15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

The gem works by monkey patching `NameError`, and prepending `DidYouMean::Correctable` to its ancestors.

```
NameError.ancestors
#=> [DidYouMean::Correctable, NameError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

You can work around this by redefining `DidYouMean::Correctable#to_s` as Wand Maker suggested, or you can remove the method from the module altogether:

```
module DidYouMean::Correctable
  remove_method :to_s
end
```

which has the same outcome.